# Cropping an image from the top in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to crop this image, which is a SKSpriteNode:

[image]

I am trying to crop this image from the top, so that I maintain the bottom semi circle of this shape. For instance, it'd be cropped to this:

[image]

So I use these two methods to accomplish this task:

```
func recalculateScore() {
    currentScore -= decreaseRate
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: (vial.texture?.cgImage())!)
    vial.texture = SKTexture(image: cropBottomImage(image: image))
}

func cropBottomImage(image: UIImage) -> UIImage {
    let height = CGFloat(image.size.height / 3)
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: image.size.height - height, width: image.size.width, height: height)
    return cropImage(image: image, toRect: rect)
}
func cropImage(image:UIImage, toRect rect:CGRect) -> UIImage {
    let imageRef:CGImage = image.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)!
    let croppedImage:UIImage = UIImage(cgImage:imageRef)
    return croppedImage
}
```

However, this leads to this result:

[image]

It is as if it was being compressed. I think my issue might be in this line:
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: image.size.height - height, width: image.size.width, height: height)

Does the CGRect coordinate of (0,0) lie within the top most left corner? I am a bit confused on what the x and y parameters for the CGRect mean?

Comment: you are not resizing your sprite, so it is stretching vertically

Comment: why you don't use SKCropNode?

Answer (score 0):

Resize your sprite, what is happening is the cropped texture is stretching to fill the sprite, and since you only crop vertically, it will only stretch vertically

```
func recalculateScore() {
    currentScore -= decreaseRate
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: (vial.texture?.cgImage())!)
    vial.texture = SKTexture(image: cropBottomImage(image: image))
    vial.size = vial.texture.size

}
```

Comment: Ok got it, does the x and y of the CGRect always relative to the top left corner?

Comment: I am going to assume you want anchor point y at zero, which is the bottom

Comment: The problem with doing vial.size = vial.texture!.size, is that vial.size is way smaller than vial.texture.size. I set setScale(ratio), yet it remains unchanged

Comment: you shouldnt be messing with scale,  if vial size is smaller than texture size, you have other problems going on